# Which term would be best to use: Falling asleep or Falling to sleep?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm tasked with filling a website with content and the client has used the term "Falling to sleep". This doesn't sound right in my head to me, I would much rather use "Falling asleep". After doing some browsing of the web, I can't find any information on which one is *better* to use in a formal context.

It is in a bullet point list and the sentence is:

> - "Difficulty initiating (falling to sleep) or maintaining sleep (staying asleep)."

The website context is about Insomnia.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! What is the context of the phrase? How does your client use it? What is the sentence trying to convey? Context is a big part of meaning.

Comment: Hello Hank. It is in a bullet point list and the sentence is:
•Difficulty initiating (falling to sleep) or maintaining sleep (staying asleep)

And the website context is about Insomnia. :)

Comment: Please add that to the OP. Not everyone who stumbles upon your post will read the comments.

Comment: To my knowledge, "falling asleep" is the usage most used. I'm not sure if "fall to sleep" is grammatically incorrect, but it's definitely not the normal usage. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=falling+asleep%2C+falling+to+sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfalling%20asleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfalling%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Fall to sleep is not grammatically correct. Unless of course you mean I battled with the sleep demon and then fell to it. But really, isn't this ELL??

Comment: @Lambie Or that I have to fall over in order to be able to sleep. Not sure which is more far-fetched.

Comment: My US ear tells me that you "fall asleep" but "go to sleep".

Answer (score 1):

You're in the majority according to the Ngram viewer. That [source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=falling%20to%20sleep%2Cfalling%20asleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfalling%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfalling%20asleep%3B%2Cc0) shows a preference for *falling asleep* over *falling to sleep* by about 100 to 1. Nevertheless, there's been a steady minority using the latter.

From [1833](https://books.google.com/books?id=TvBXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA272&dq=%22fall%20to%20sleep%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPv4OV_czRAhWL5oMKHfklAoIQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=%22fall%20to%20sleep%22&f=false):

> The convicts on going to rest ever talk of their pardons soon coming down, and **fall to sleep** offering each other bets regarding which of them will first obtain his liberty.

From [1889](https://books.google.com/books?id=_qhXAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA484&dq=%22falling%20to%20sleep%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkpruT_8zRAhUETCYKHfGhBFQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22falling%20to%20sleep%22&f=false):

> The main point to be observed in hypnotizing is to bring the subject into such a position that he will be aided in **falling to sleep**.

From [1905](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fall%20to%20sleep%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1888,cd_max:1956&lr=lang_en):

> A sleeper can be aroused to say "leave me alone " and'then f**all to sleep** without any recollection of the disturbance.

From [1939](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fall%20to%20sleep%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1888,cd_max:1956&lr=lang_en):

> If left to himself a child will sleep — he will even **fall to sleep** over his dinner or at his play. It requires no learning to **fall to sleep** when the body is too tired to stay awake.

From [1999](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fell%20to%20sleep%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1981,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en):

> I **fell to sleep** immediately. When I began to awake to the song of a cardinal outside my window, I was dreaming.

Comment: A fair few of those are by obviously non-native writers, and many of the ones that aren't seem to be the result of mixing up _falling asleep_ and _getting to sleep_. There are only a few of them that really seem like they deliberately wrote _falling to sleep_. And even with all the non-natives and mixer-uppers, there are still about 300 times as many instances of _fall(ing)/fell asleep_ as _fall(ing)/fell to sleep_, so it's a **very** small minority.

Comment: This is an excellent example of where ngram (or google) does not work. You take a mistake, then search for it, and when it turns up some number of times alongside another unquestionable form, you say those who use the unquestionable form are a majority. How specious is that?

Comment: @Lambie And whom are we supposed to accept as the unquestionable judge of "mistakes"? You? How specious is *that*? The very large majority use *asleep*. But we can find published, literate examples of *to sleep* in continuous use over the last 200 years.

Comment: @deadrat It is seemingly a conundrum but not really. Do you accept that in English, we do not say: he has 20 years old? That that is unidiomatic in English? Do you accept that to say: /We go off the bus at 6:00 pm/ does not mean /We get off the bus at 6:00/? For me, fall TO sleep is unidiomatic. Just like those examples and they are not really googleable or ngramable. And only real people (like the person typing this) can make that kind of statement. It's not algorithmable, as it were.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet And how did you determine that the authors didn't "deliberately" use *to sleep*? Feel free to use my additional cites.

Comment: To sleep, perchance to dream, aye, there's the rub. If you see fall to sleep on a website about insomnia, one can only conclude: it was not properly proofread or edited. Oh, and lastly, the client is uneducated, poorly educated and most definitely not a writer.

Comment: @Lambie Ah, it's unidiomatic to *you*. Well, say no more. Never mind that all my examples are from published books. As long the authors weren't "algorithmable".

Comment: @Lambie None of my examples is from websites. Go figure.

Comment: @deadrat Of course, it's unidiomatic TO ME. A phrase is only idiomatic or unidiomatic to a native speaker and usually editors and translators do not argue about things like: fall to sleep, for pete's sake. They argue about much more complicated things. And you did not respond to my questions to ***you***. You may be as sarcastic as you like, it matters little to me. Also, JanusBahsJacquet is writing FOR a client. He's not tasked with writing poetry, literature or other non-standard FORMS.

Comment: @Lambie Well, excuse me. Where did I get the idea that you were declaiming on mistaken usage and not just expressing your tastes? Another thing editors might not argue about is uncommon but acceptable usage. What possible difference could my answers to your unrelated questions make? About as much as JBJ's task list, I suspect. At least the sarcasm is getting through. Perhaps the point will follow.

Comment: @You have still  not answered my questions. I see this a lot. Sometimes when the oneupmanship does not work, the other person will do anything at all to discredit the interlocutor. I was not just expressing my "my tastes". My questions go DIRECTLY to the idea we are discussing.  You seem to think that something printed in a book makes it the word of the linguistic overlords. Apparently, you missed the point: writing a text on insomnia for a website (the context here), not writing a poem on insomnia for The New Yorker. So really, ingrams ***et cie.***, to be snobby, have zero value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52046/discussion-between-deadrat-and-lambie).